# cv2.findContours not able to detect contours

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

I have two binary images and I am trying to detect the contours of the white patches in them (the pink outline in the right of the collage is the contour result).

`cv2.contourFind()` is working fine for Contour1:

[image: Contour1 Image & Result]

But for Contour2 it's acting weird:

[image: Contour2 Image & Result]

Here is the function call for it

```
#Convert Image to grayscale
img = cv2.imread(file_name)
img2gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, mask = cv2.threshold(img2gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 3))
dilated = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel, iterations=2)
image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilated.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for contour in contours:
    [x, y, w, h] = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 255), 2)
```

Using this `contours` variable I draw rectangles around the points found.
I don't understand why it works for Contour1, but fails for Contour2 when they look pretty similar.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Done, @AlexanderReynolds

Comment: How many contours are in `contours` for each image?

Comment: 102 for Contour1, and 1 for Contour2

Comment: View the output image at each step (converting color, thresholding, dilating) and see what is happening to the image prior to finding the contours. See if that gives any indication of issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Mistake**: The binary image had a thin white border box in Contour2 but not in Contour1 (my bad!). Since I asked for *only* external contours, `cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL` in

```
image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilated.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

for Contour2 had only the outermost box detected and hence none of its children got drawn. But in Contour1 there is no white border box around the binary image hence the internal white blobs got detected.

**Solution**: Use `cv2.RETR_LIST` or `cv2.RETR_CCOMP`